# Using firebase-query with Polymerfire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

Before anyone makes a comment about me not trying to figure things out on my own.

I have read through those firebase docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) about 3 times today. I also read through the source code ( e.g. https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/master/firebase-query.html) about 3 times today.

I essentially have data setup like this:

```
{
Logs: {
$uid: {
$logID:{
logMetaData}}},

Users: {
$uid:{
userMetaData}},

Groups: {
admin: {
members: {
$uid}},
users: {
members: {
$uid}}}
}
```

I’m trying to use `firebase-query` like this:

```
<firebase-query
      id="adminLogQuery"
      app-name="Nuclear Medicine Log"
      path="/Logs/"
      orderByChild="Authorized User"
      equalTo="{"[[user.displayName]]":"Authorized User"}
      data="{{data}}">
</firebase-query>
```

Essentially, within the `logMetaData`, there is a key called `Authorized User` and I want to match the `user.displayName` to the values for the `Authorized User`.

I would like to define `path="Logs/[[uid]/[[logId]]"` but I’m not sure how I would have `uid` or `logID` defined (or pre-defined) as properties, since there are so many entries that vary. The `uid` is a scramble of letters and numbers, while the `logID` are timestamps

I’m not sure if `orderByChild` traverses multiple levels that are deep to the root.

Comment: Polymer attributes don't follow camel case naming. So orderByChild should be order-by-child. And equalTo should be equal-to.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I think that it's the solution. I will try and comment back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer attributes don't follow camel case naming. So orderByChild should be order-by-child. And equalTo should be equal-to.